# API receiving Half Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

I have a PHP API but when I send data to it using a post or get request the API receives half data, I don't know what the issue is. this same API works on the localhost but gives error on the Public server.

**API sendrequset URL:**
https://peer.infusiblecoder.com/android/loanapp/sendrequesttoperson.php?request_is_seen=hjhj&loan_request_code=100&req_status=hjh&request_sender_user_name=ghjgjh&request_reciver_user_name=hjhjh&request_sender_user_id=jkjkj&request_reciver_user_id=hjhj&request_time_stamp=ghhgjhh

**And this is my Api sendrequesttoperson.php**

```html
<?php
require 'db.php';



if(isset( $_GET["$req_status_db"]) && isset($_GET["$loan_request_code_db"]) && isset($_GET["$request_sender_user_name_db"]) && isset($_GET["$request_reciver_user_name_db"]) && isset($_GET["$request_sender_user_id_db"]) && isset($_GET["$request_reciver_user_id_db"]) && isset($_GET["$request_is_seen_db"]) && isset($_GET["$request_time_stamp_db"])){
 
  $loan_request_code = $_GET["$loan_request_code_db"];
 $request_sender_user_name = $_GET["$request_sender_user_name_db"];
 $request_reciver_user_name = $_GET["$request_reciver_user_name_db"];
 
 $request_sender_user_id = $_GET["$request_sender_user_id_db"];
 $request_reciver_user_id = $_GET["$request_reciver_user_id_db"];
 $request_time_stamp = $_GET["$request_time_stamp_db"];
 $request_is_seen = $_GET["$request_is_seen_db"];
$req_status = $_GET["$req_status_db"];
 


 
 $sql = "select * from $table_requests where $loan_request_code_db like '".$loan_request_code."';";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $response = array();

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  
  $code = "failed";
  $message = "Request already exists";
  array_push($response, array("code" => $code, "message" => $message));
  echo json_encode($response);
  
 } else {
  
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_requests VALUES (NULL,'$loan_request_code','$request_sender_user_name','$request_reciver_user_name','$request_sender_user_id','$request_reciver_user_id','$request_time_stamp','$request_is_seen','$req_status')";
 
 

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
 
 
 
  $code = "success";
  $message = "Request sent";
  array_push($response, array("code" => $code, "message" => $message));
  echo json_encode($response);

    echo "Request sent successfully";
} else {
    
 
 $code = "failed";
  $message = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
  array_push($response, array("code" => $code, "message" => $message));
  echo json_encode($response);
 
 
 
 
 
}

  //$message = "Thank you for registration";

//  array_push($response, array("code" => $code, "message" => $message));
 // echo json_encode($response);
 }

 mysqli_close($con);
 
}else{

  $loan_request_code = $_GET["$loan_request_code_db"];
 $request_sender_user_name = $_GET["$request_sender_user_name_db"];
 $request_reciver_user_name = $_GET["$request_reciver_user_name_db"];
 
 $request_sender_user_id = $_GET["$request_sender_user_id_db"];
 $request_reciver_user_id = $_GET["$request_reciver_user_id_db"];
 $request_time_stamp = $_GET["$request_time_stamp_db"];
 $request_is_seen = $_GET["$request_is_seen_db"];
$req_status = $_GET["$req_status_db"];


 $myresponse = 'Enter missing fields_'.$request_sender_user_name."_".$loan_request_code."_".$request_reciver_user_name."_".$request_sender_user_id."_".$request_reciver_user_id."_".$request_time_stamp."_".$request_is_seen."_".$req_status."_";
 
 echo json_encode($myresponse);
 
 

}



?>
```

**And this is my db.php file required for the variable names and db connection**

```html
<?php 

$host = "localhost";
$db_user = "ur5kq7835fnc4";
$db_password ="ch%2@3/^c<1b";
$db_name = "dbhrzz2e49skck";



//Folder Path
$mainpath = "http://192.168.0.101/android/loanapp/";

$profilepic_folder = "profilepics/";

$fileupload_folder="uploadedFiles/";

$fileuploadfullpath_folder="uploadedFiles/";
 
// loan request statuses {"pending", "rejected","accepted","awaiting money", "paid out", "completed"};



// Table RegisteredUser attributes:

$table_user = "registered_users";

$user_id_db = "user_id";
$firstname_db = "firstname";
$lastname_db = "lastname";
$address_db = "address";
$whatyoupretend_db = "whatyoupretend";
$fieldofactivity_db = "fieldofactivity";
$phone_db = "phone";
$email_db = "email";
$password_db = "password";
$status_db = "status";
$user_img_url_db = "user_img_url";



// Table LoanRequest attributes:

$table_loan_request = "loan_request";

$loan_id_db = "loan_id";
$loan_request_code_db = "loan_request_code";
$user_full_name_db = "user_full_name";
$user_img_url_request_db = "user_img_url_request";


$loan_amount_db = "loan_amount";
$loan_purpose_db = "loan_purpose";
$loan_collateral_db = "loan_collateral";
$loan_market_value_db = "loan_market_value";
$loan_type_db = "loan_type";

$loan_due_date_db = "loan_due_date";

$loan_doc_urls_db = "loan_doc_urls";
$loan_borrowing_rate_db ="loan_borrowing_rate";
$loan_loan_ratio_db ="loan_loan_ratio";
$loan_status_db = "loan_status";
$loan_paid_out_date_db ="loan_paid_out_date";
$loan_duration_db = "loan_duration";
//loan_duration
//loan_paid_out_date

// Table Requests
$table_loan_request = "loan_request";

$loan_id_db = "loan_id";
$loan_request_code_db = "loan_request_code";
$user_full_name_db = "user_full_name";
$user_img_url_request_db = "user_img_url_request";


$loan_amount_db = "loan_amount";
$loan_purpose_db = "loan_purpose";
$loan_collateral_db = "loan_collateral";
$loan_market_value_db = "loan_market_value";
$loan_type_db = "loan_type";

$loan_due_date_db = "loan_due_date";

$loan_doc_urls_db = "loan_doc_urls";
$loan_borrowing_rate_db ="loan_borrowing_rate";
$loan_loan_ratio_db ="loan_loan_ratio";
$loan_status_db = "loan_status";
$loan_lender_id_db = "loan_lender_id";
$loan_paid_out_date_db ="loan_paid_out_date";
$loan_duration_db = "loan_duration";

/*
Table User attributes:

tbname = registered_users

user_id
firstname
lastname
address
whatyoupretend
fieldofactivity
phone
email
password
status [true,false]
user_img_url

*/

/*
Table LoanRequest attributes:

tbname = loan_request

loan_id
loan_request_code
user_full_name
loan_amount
loan_purpose
loan_collateral
loan_market_value
loan_type
loan_due_date

loan_doc_vehicle_id_url
loan_doc_owner_id_url
loan_doc_insurance_url
loan_status

Vehicle ID,Owner´s ID,Insurance

*/

/*
Table Requests attributes:

tbname = requests

request_id
loan_request_code
request_sender_user_name
request_reciver_user_name
request_sender_user_id
request_reciver_user_id
request_time_stamp
request_is_seen


*/



$con = mysqli_connect($host, $db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

if (!$con){
 
 die("connection failed". mysqli_connect_error());
 
}
/*
else{
 echo "connected susscesful";
}
*/

 ?>
```

**it gives this result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$_GET["$req_status_db"]`

It should be `$_GET["req_status_db"]`

You will have to remove `$` from all the $_GET keys.

Also, you do not have req_status_db as query param in the URL you have shared.